# Hide textbox in one div with click of button in another div

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
<%foreach (var commentitem in item.commentsModelList)
   {
        var containerId = "comment-" + commentitem.CommentId;%>
       <div id="commentContainer1">
       <div id="<%:containerId %>">
       <table border="0"  class="commentbox">

        <%var rid = "btnReply-" + commentitem.CommentId;
          var replyContainer = "container-" + commentitem.CommentId;%>
       <tr>

        <td> 
         <div id="<%:replyContainer %>">
          <input id="<%:rid %>" type="button" value="Reply" class="btnReply"/>
          </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
 </div>
</div>
  <%} %>
```

JQUERY

```
     $(".commentbox .btnReply").live("click", function () {
            $(this).hide();
        var id = $(this).attr("id").split("-");
            alert(id);
            id.shift();
            alert(id);
            var newString = id.join('-');
            alert(newString);


            var $table = $('<table/>').addClass('tablecontent');
            $table.append(
                        $('<tr>').append($('<td>').append($input))
                             );
```

**Edited**

```
            $($table).insertAfter("#container-" + newString).show();
        //     $("#container-" + newString).append($table);
        });
```

When reply button in one div is clicked textbox appears but when Reply button in another div is clicked I want the textbox in previous div to disappear.
I am trying to duplicate the [functionality on this page](http://androidos.in/2012/03/htc-outs-list-of-16-devices-planned-for-ice-cream-sandwich-updates/comment-page-1/#comment-130055).

I have created fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rgmtF/16/

Comment: Has this question been solved? Please mark the selected answer if so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What would be much easier is to create the reply area first and then move those nodes to the corresponding area. This will greatly simplify your code and will scale better when you make changes.

Mentioned in the code above is many pre-populated id's that denote which comment is which. I don't see any point to utilizing these id's as this isn't something that will be used for replying to multiple comments. What I'd suggest is to keep the comment area fields static and use a hidden field to denote what comment you are replying to.

You could wrap this in a nice function but the principle is still the same.

I've created a sample which uses different HTML but I think illustrates the idea in the most minimal fashion.

http://jsfiddle.net/ubTDD/1/
(This fiddle is heavily documented)

Comment: $("[id^=reply]") what does this indicate

Comment: you code is perfect but it is not getting reflected in my code

Comment: $($table).insertAfter("#container-" + newString).show(); it is not working

Comment: @prerna I've created a new fiddle using what I think is correct. Thi time heavily commented. jsfiddle.net/ubTDD/1

Comment: that is perfectly fine but what is the problem with my code where I am creating dom dynamically...can u help in that

Answer (score 3):

why not introduce a new css class to represent "selected" state at the commentContainer level, ie addClass("selected").

When you click on Reply

```
$(".commentbox .btnReply").live("click", function(){
  $('.commentContainer.selected').hide();  //hide previously selected comment divs if any
  $(this).parents('.commentContainer').addClass('selected');  //mark current as selected

  ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide all previously visible textboxes when reply button is clicked, just add one line of code in your click event. e.g main container div id is "master"

```
$("#master input[type=text]")​.hide();​
```

Better is to hide a complete block of elements including text boxes via class name.

```
$(".tablecontent").hide();
```

Sample code will look like

```
$(".commentbox .btnReply").live("click", function () {
      $(".tablecontent").hide();
      $(this).hide();
      ....
});
```

Comment: but this is hiding Reply button of other div also

Comment: reply button class is "btnReply" and you will hide "tablecontent" which represent table. It will not effect reply button if reply button not within table.

Comment: to avoid any confusion, try to separate reply button and reply box in two different elements.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can work around that in the following mannar:
1.Give the divsion of reply button, a name. For ex- `<input id="<%:rid %>" type="button" value="Reply" class="btnReply"/>`
2.Give the division of textarea you want to hide, a class name. For ex- "textarea".
Now I would go in the following mannar:

```
$(".commentbox .btnReply").live("click", function () {
      if ($('.textarea').is(':hidden')) {
         alert("Textarea is already hidden"); //check if already hidden
      } else {
         $('.textarea').hide();   //if not, then hide the textarea
      }
      ....
      ....
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply either add a common class name to all your textbox or have some jquery selector which targets all the textboxes related to the reply buttons present on page and then use the common class name or the selector to first hide all the textboxes before showing the specific one related to the reply button which is clicked.

Hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('your-button-selector').click(function(){
  $('your-textbox-selector').slideUp();
  //$('your-textbox-selector').slideToggle();//use this to toggle show and hide
});
```

Or use:

```
<input type="button" name="sample-button" onclick="hideTextbox('textbox-selector')"/>
function hideTextbox(selector){
  $(selector).hide();
  //$(selector).slideToggle();
}
```